# How to select multiples HTML elments with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to select using jquery all the li elements with id=result-XX that are active (class=.... active).

The HTML page has:

```
<li id="result-1" class="list-group-item hover active">
</li>
<li id="result-2" class="list-group-item hover">
</li>
<li id="result-3" class="list-group-item hover">
</li>
```

I have tried the following (only for select the list of results) but it does not work:

```
console.log("Result: " + $('li[id^="result-1"').length);
console.log("Result: " + $("li:contains('result-')").length);
console.log("Result: " + $("li[id~='result-']").length);
```

Then, we need to get only the active ones.

Comment: $('li.active[id^="result-"]') will do the job

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first one should work, but your selector is wrong. It should be `$('li[id^="result-"]')`.

You could use `$('li[id^="result-"]').filter(".active")` to reduce the set to just the `active` ones, e.g.

```
var elements, activeElements;
elements = $('li[id^="result-"]');
activeElements = elements.filter(".active");
```

See http://api.jquery.com/filter/

Comment: missing square bracket? Same reason why the first will not work

Comment: @jenson-button-event Why you wont commit that edit on my post.? That is a valid one right.? missing square brackets.?

Comment: @Raj - erm not sure what you mean, someone has left some comments in the actual post about a missing square bracket which is actually there - so i removed them. `$('li[id^="result-"].active')` is what i see

Comment: @jenson-button-event Thanks for spotting that! Fixed it. I even corrected it in another answer...

Answer (score 5):

Lets break down the selector needed:

1. `li` - this will match all `li` elements. [Element selector](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/)
2. `[id^="result-"]` - this will match all elements whose `id` attribute starts with `result-`. [Starts with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/).
3. `.active` - this will match all elements that have the `active` class on them. [Class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)

Combining them will give you the final selector that you need:

```
var elements = $( 'li.active[id^="result-"]' );
```

---

To give this a little more readability, I would suggest writing it like this:

```
var elements = $( 'li[id^="result-"]' ).has( '.active' );
```

This uses the [has()](http://api.jquery.com/has/) filter to reduce the set of matched elements to only those who *have* the `active` class.

Comment: The first part is ok. I don't know why but the ".has( '.active' )" method does not work. Combining with the Olly Hodgson's proposal (.filter) it works ok. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You have to combine the [**`attribute starts with selector`**](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) along with the [**`class selector`**](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) to accomplish your task.

Try,

```
$('li[id^="result-"].active')
```

Comment: @Olly Thanks.. That was a typo. Really thanks for pointing the mistake.

Comment: I think ppl are messing with the down-vote just for fun... I up voted for good answer

Comment: ^^, yup. people down vote just to down vote. With no comment. Your answer is ok, but read the ops question and try to give them a way to select these elements as they asked.

Comment: it's ok if you remove 1 from "result-1" expression

Comment: If anyone gives down-vote than explain the reason too.

Comment: The downvote was because they asked for a way to select  the elements, not for a length, i didn't downvote, but it deserves it unless you edit

Comment: This returns the number of matching elements - not the elements themselves.